# change brand details by selecting options javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, reactjs

default i want to display all product details, i want to change the matching product details if option value === products b_name .. display the details

```js
let products = [
        {
            b_name: 'Samsung',
            price: 15000,
            ram: '6GB',
            rom: '128GB',
        },
        {
            b_name: 'Apple',
            price: 65000,
            ram: '6GB',
            rom: '128GB',
        },
{
        b_name: 'LG',
        price: 35000,
        ram: '6GB',
        rom: '128GB',
    },
    {
        b_name: 'Nokia',
        price: 25000,
        ram: '6GB',
        rom: '128GB',
    },
    ];
    
     let _selectBrand =   $('#select_brand');
   let _detailsList = $('#details');
   let brandOptions = '';
    for(let brand of  products){
       brandOptions += `<option value="${brand.b_name}">${brand.b_name}</option>`;
    }
    _selectBrand.append(brandOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>
        <select id="select_brand">
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="details">
</div>
```

Comment: You could achieve your requirements without using JQuery. If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through the Angular tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces some of the basics.

Comment: Where do you want to show all product details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, All you need to do is detect on change event and do a lookup in your list.

```
 $('#select_brand').change(function() {
   for(let brand of products){
      if(this.value === brand.b_name){
        _detailsList.text(JSON.stringify(brand))
      }
   }
});
```

> ***Just Copy Paste this snippet and observe the logic.***

I understand there can be a tone of optimization and edge cases but for this data set you provided, my solution should work just fine.